# How to preselect initial text in the minibuffer with Elisp?

Tags: minibuffer, region, string, interactive, read

I'm using `read-string` to read a string from the minibuffer, with an initial input. How can I highlight the initial input, so that I can start replacing it with one key stroke? IOW, given `(read-string "Test: " "Input")` how can I put `Input` in an active region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use macro `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` to set the mark at the end of the minibuffer prompt.  `read-string` then inserts the initial text with the mark active, which means that initial text is selected as the active region.

```lisp
(defun foo (strg)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (list (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
             (lambda () (set-mark (minibuffer-prompt-end)))
           (read-string "Test: " "Input"))))
  (message "STRING: %s" strg))
```

Comment: Thank you Drew!